# Extracting netCDF time series for each lat/long in Matlab

Tags: matlab, netcdf

I'm currently working with netCDF output from climate models and would like to obtain a text file of the time series for each latitude/longitude combination in the netCDF. For example, if the netCDF has 10 latitudes and 10 longitudes I would obtain 100 text files, each with a time series in a column format. I'm fairly familiar with the Matlab/netCDF language, but I can't seem to wrap my head around this. Naming the text files is not important; I will rename them "latitude_longitude_PCP.txt", where PCP is precipitation at the latitude and longitude location.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

--Darren

Comment: Curious to know why you want them in separate files. Are you working with really large data (compared to the ram on your machine) that your analysis would work only with one time series at a time?

Comment: I am extracting separate time series so that I can input them into a hydrologic model, which uses a weather time series for lat/long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways this problem could be solved.

Method 1. If you were able to put your netcdf file on a THREDDS Data Server, you could use the NetCDF Subset Service Grid as Point to specify a longitude/latitude point and get back the data in CSV or XML format.  Here's an example from Unidata's THREDDS Data Server: http://thredds.ucar.edu/thredds/ncss/grid/grib/NCEP/GFS/Global_0p5deg/best/pointDataset.html

Method 2. If you wanted to use Matlab to extract a time series at a specific longitude/latitude location you could use the "nj_tseries" function from NCTOOLBOX, available at: http://nctoolbox.github.io/nctoolbox/

Method 3. If you really want to write an ASCII time series at every i,j location in your [time,lon,lat] grid using Matlab, you could do something like this (using NCTOOLBOX):

```
url='http://thredds.ucar.edu/thredds/dodsC/grib/NCEP/GFS/Global_2p5deg/best';
nc = ncgeodataset(url);
nc.variables
var='Downward_Short-Wave_Radiation_Flux_surface_12_Hour_Average';
lon = nc.data('lon');
lat = nc.data('lat');
jd = nj_time(nc,var);
ncvar = nc.variable(var);
for j=1:length(lat)
    for i=1:length(lon)
        v=ncvar.data(:,j,i);
        outfile=sprintf('%6.2flon%6.2flat.csv',lon(i),lat(j))
        fid=fopen(outfile,'wt')
        data= [datevec(jd) v]
        fprintf(fid,'%2.2d %2.2d %2.2d %2.2d %2.2d %2.2d %7.2f\n',data')
        fclose(fid)
        disp([outfile ' created.'])
    end
end
```

If you had enough memory to read all the data into matlab, you could read outside the double loop, which would be a lot faster.  But writing ASCII is slow anyway, so it might not matter that much.

Answer (score 0):

```
%% Create demo data 
data = reshape(1:20*30*40,[20 30 40]);
nccreate('t.nc','data','Dimensions',{'lat', 20, 'lon',30, 'time', inf});
ncwrite('t.nc', 'data',data);
ncdisp('t.nc');

%% Write timeseries to ASCII files
% Giving an idea of the size of your data can help people 
% recommend different approaches tailored to the data size. 
% For smaller data, it might be faster to read in the full 
% 3D data into memory
varInfo = ncinfo('t.nc','data');
disp(varInfo);
for latInd =1:varInfo.Size(1)
    for lonInd =1:varInfo.Size(2)
        fileName = ['t_ascii_lat',num2str(latInd),'_lon',num2str(lonInd),'.txt'];
        tSeries  = ncread('t.nc','data',[latInd, lonInd, 1],[1,1,varInfo.Size(3)]);
        dlmwrite(fileName,squeeze(tSeries));
    end
end

%% spot check
act = dlmread('t_ascii_lat10_lon29.txt');
exp = squeeze(data(10,29,:));
assert(isequal(act,exp));
```